# Can I make FaceTime the default audio- and video-call app when other call apps are installed?

Tags: iphone, facetime

I installed Microsoft Teams on my iPhone because I need it for work. But now when I click a Favorite in the Phone app so I can call someone, the default in the list for making an audio call or a video call is Teams. I have to click the tiny drop-down button to select *mobile* for calls or *FaceTime* for video calls. Is there a way to move Teams down the list so I can default to regular phone calls and FaceTime for video calls?

Also from any Contact screen, clicking Video to make a video call defaults to Teams at the top of the list.

Not jail-broken. iPhone 8. iOS 13.4.1

Comment: have you searched for relevant settings in Settings app ?

Comment: There is no option to do this currently. Apple might offer a default settings option in iOS 14.

Comment: ankii, Yes, didn't see anything promising. Todd, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make Facetime Default audio video call app on your iPhone by following below mentioned steps:

1. Tap Apps & Notifications.
2. Tap Advanced.
3. Tap Default Apps.
4. Under Default Apps, you will find 'Phone App' which you can tap to change the default.